# faster php copy() function ( for remote )  like more connection?

Tags: php

I take the some youtube videos to my server with copy(); function but youtube give approximately 100kb/s speed with one connection ( my server has 100 mbit/s connection )

Is it possible to take more then 1 connection and reach faster speed with copy() function or sth else ?

Comment: PHP is single threaded what you're asking for is not 'decently' possible but sure you can open x socket connections and poll each for data in a loop but that sucks.

Comment: AFAIK, Youtube throttles the video download depending on the video's bitrate to save bandwidth since the videos are meant to be streamed not downloaded

Comment: There are lots of expensive application for windows to download youtube videos and/or convert it , They are stealing videos, are they ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to download / copy multiple URL from an external source concurrently,
[curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) is what you are look for.

This is a library made to synchronous curl multiple URL,
with the expenses of network bandwidth (and perhaps a little of CPU)

If you are looking to split a download,
once again, [curl has the split option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)

```
RANGES

  With HTTP 1.1 byte-ranges were introduced. Using this, a client can request
  to get only one or more subparts of a specified document. Curl supports
  this with the -r flag.

  Get the first 100 bytes of a document:

        curl -r 0-99 http://www.get.this/

  Get the last 500 bytes of a document:

        curl -r -500 http://www.get.this/

  Curl also supports simple ranges for FTP files as well. Then you can only
  specify start and stop position.

  Get the first 100 bytes of a document using FTP:

        curl -r 0-99 ftp://www.get.this/README
```

Comment: I think he wants to download different chunks in parallel for the same file instead of downloading multiple urls simultaneously

Comment: oh, not sure, if OP looking for download some videos, this should be the way to go.